# Filtering angular repeats

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to create a filter for Angular.js

Controller.js sample snippet:

```
function TitleListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.titles = [
    { "name": "Foobar",
      "editions": 
        [{"print": true, 
          "ebook": false,
          "audio": false }]
    },
   { "name": "FooBarBar",
      "editions": 
        [{"print": false, 
          "ebook": false,
          "audio": false }]
   }
];}
```

Angular html:

```
<ul ng-controller="TitleListCtrl">
        <li class="TitleList" ng-repeat="title in titles 
                                         | filter:isUpcoming 
                                         | orderBy:'date'">{{title.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I'm trying to return only those titles who have no active editions (no members of the edition array is set to true). Finding it hard to find examples online doing something like this...

```
$scope.isUpcoming = function(title) {
return title.editions[0] & title.editions[1] & title.editions[2]===false;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the above approach, I used data-ng-show:

```
<ul ng-controller="TitleListCtrl">
<li class="TitleList" data-ng-show="!(title.upcoming)" 
                                    ng-repeat="title in titles 
                                    | filter:query 
                                    | orderBy:'date'">{{title.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And added a new pair `"upcoming": true,` for titles where needed.

```
function TitleListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.titles = [
    { "name": "Foobar",
  "editions": 
    [{"print": true, 
      "ebook": false,
      "audio": false }]
    },
   { "name": "FooBarBar",
  "editions": 
    [{"print": false, 
      "ebook": false,
      "audio": false }],
  "upcoming": true
   }
];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/SkXnZhwic8KHWvj0JyFI?p=preview.

It implements a custom filter which filters out the long list to upcoming list and then renders the upcoming list